# Regex to exclude a substring that exists before a certain substring

Tags: ruby, regex

Any idea on how to write a regular expression that matches a substring 'urgent' as long as it doesn't contain 'not' before 'urgent'?

ex.

`this is urgent` - match!
`[not urgent] blah` - don't match

For Ruby 1.9.2, this works
`/(?<!not )urgent/`
-uses negative look behind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
/(?=.*urgent)(?!.*not urgent)(^.*$)/
```

Sample match: http://regexr.com?2trsp

Comment: @alex `/(?!=not )urgent/` - ok, the lookaheads and lookbehinds see the actual main expression ( in this case `urgent` ) and make sure the pattern in the lookahead is present / not present in the main expression. So all that `/(?!=not )urgent/` does is match `urgent` provided `urgent` is not `=not `. It is not like you are saying `not` shouldn't come before `urgent`

Comment: In my regular expression, the main expression is `^.*$` and the lookaheads ensures that only `urgent` is there and not `not urgent`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation! :) I've found another solution as well but it works in only 1.9.2. Yours works even in 1.8.7. Thanks!